# PHP export û (u with circumflex) from MySQL utf8_general_ci: not working

Tags: php, mysql, character-encoding

I have a mysql table with a character stored as "û" (u with a circumflex). I am exporting this via php to csv. I have tried everyhting but just cant get û in the export file. I do see things like "?" or "È" and "Ã»".

**Question**: how can I properly export the data from mysql to a CSV file using PHP so I see "û" in the DB as "û" in the exported file?

Our php drill

```
mb_internal_encoding("UTF-8");
$list = $readConnection->fetchAll($query);
$fp = fopen($file, 'w');
setlocale(LC_MONETARY, 'nl_NL');

# Loop over lines here
$line = utf8_encode($db_row);
fputcsv($fp, $line);
```

I have also tried adding a BOM `fprintf($fp, chr(0xEF).chr(0xBB).chr(0xBF)); // set UTF 8 header, not working`

Comment: Just a minor comment: the trema is the two-dot diacritical mark, and u with trema is `ü` instead of `û`, which is the u with a circumflex.

Comment: @Phylogenesis & deceze : I think the duplicate tag is set just a little too fast and seems to be done only based on title. For example this question is not even about Excel!

Comment: Correct & adjusted. circumflex

Comment: And this answer is maybe less "all the way through" https://stackoverflow.com/questions/279170/utf-8-all-the-way-through -- set names is no answer here .... and maybe the reason why I have just spent 1 hour reading blogs and answers about this ... that did not give the simple answer

Comment: I'm not sure how it's different at all. The fix was to ensure the database connection is set to UTF-8, then `fputcsv` will output the bytes as received from the database, which is UTF-8. Anything more particular that needed addressing?

Comment: Well ..... the title is "UTF-8 all the way through" versus "PHP export û (u with circumflex) from MySQL utf8_general_ci" which is a lot more specific .... it covers 1 specific case. And not "all the way through" - you also know it is different because the answers are not the same

Comment: There are many questions which are smaller in scope, but they all have the same underlying root cause: in 99% of all cases (anecdotally speaking), the issue is a missing database connection charset. We don't need to address that again and again for every possible use case permutation.

Comment: `?` and Mojibake (such as `Ã»`) are symptoms of two different causes.  See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38363566/trouble-with-utf8-characters-what-i-see-is-not-what-i-stored for discussion of both.

Comment: @deceze - Note that "all the way thru" says what you should do, while my SO Q&A addresses 5 _different_ symptoms with different causes.

Comment: @deceze - 99% is a bit excessive.  There are 4-6 _different_ things that need to be done.  Uses sometimes have more than one thing wrong.

Comment: thx. Sorry but the articles *did not* help me. And the Excel reference is not even the same topic. This answer did.

Comment: Why is this question tagged with [mysql]?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The anwer is to execute `SET NAMES utf8` to the DB before you query data. All other settings are fine. The function `utf8_encode` is then also no longer needed.

**The drill then becomes**

```
mb_internal_encoding("UTF-8");
$list = $readConnection->fetchAll($query);
$readConnection->query("SET NAMES utf8");

$fp = fopen($file, 'w');
setlocale(LC_MONETARY, 'nl_NL');

# Loop over lines here
$line = $db_row;
fputcsv($fp, $line);
```

Please be aware! when checking this to use a TEXT editor. Excel uses a different encoding and will still show the characters as "È—" for example. When opening with a text editor we see the expected "û" character.